Calculate standard deviation
I'm studying an ecological community comprising three samples, each representing different habitats within the community. Within each sample, I've conducted three replicates, summing nine replicates overall. The average number of species observed in each sample is 6 (standard deviation = 0.5), 11 (standard deviation = 2), and 21 (standard deviation = 3), respectively. I want to know the total number of species for the community, irrespective of habitats. To do this, I've summed the average species across all plots (in total, 6 + 11 + 21 = 38 species).
Now, my question is: how can I determine the standard deviation for the entire ecological community?

Standard deviation of what, exactly?  It looks like there's no information in these summary statistics to enable us to determine the amount of overlap in numbers of distinct species among the habitats, and isn't that a critical factor?

Standard deviation of the community regardless the habitats

Because standard deviations are functions of collections of numbers, and "community" does not ordinarily suggest a collection of numbers, please help us connect these concepts.  As I pointed out, if you mean numbers of distinct species, then it would seem you lack the information to develop a meaningful standard deviation of anything related to that from these data.
